# Asp.Net Core Razor Pages Friendly URLs

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

Trying to get friendly URL's working with Razor Pages, here is my folder structure within the `Pages` folder:

```
/Products/Index.cshtml @page
/Products/View.cshtml @page "{id}/view"
/Products/Process.cshtml @page "{id}/process"
```

I'm linking from `Index.cshtml` to the other pages like this:

```
<a asp-page="/Products/View" asp-route-id="100">View</a>

<a asp-page="/Products/Process" asp-route-id="100">Process</a>
```

The generated urls are `products/view/100/view` and `products/process/100/process`.

Instead is it possible to generate them like `products/100/view` and `products/100/process`?

I've tried `asp-page="View" asp-route-id="100"`, but that makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

grrr, jumped too soon, this worked:

```
@page "/products/{id}/view"

@page "/products/{id}/process"
```

Coffee...